# Can't Increase-Decrease font size

Tags: javascript, html

I want to increase and decrease font size continuously. It just ain't happening. It increases but then stops and starts flickering like something is stopping it from decreasing.
Tell me whats wrong here.

```js
 var change = document.querySelector("p");
    change.style.fontSize = "20px";
    var t = 20;
    setInterval(function(){
        t++;
        change.style.fontSize = t+"px";
        if(t==50){
            setInterval(function(){
                t--;
                change.style.fontSize = t+"px";
                if(t==20){
                    clearInterval();
                }
            },50);
        }  
    },50);
```

```html
<p>example text</p>
```

Comment: Your outer setInterval keeps running (+) even when your inner setInterval is running too (-). So in that scenario, you will always be doing +1 -1 over and over.

Comment: so how can I stop it from doing that ? I can't figure it out.

Comment: set the intervals into a variable and clear the outer interval when the inner one starts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toggleFontSize(selector, init, increase = true) {
  selector.style.fontSize = `${init}px`;

  const handle = setInterval(function() {
    init = increase ? init + 1 : init - 1;
    selector.style.fontSize = `${init}px`;
    if (init == 50 && increase) {
      clearInterval(handle);
      toggleFontSize(selector, init, false);
    } else if (init == 20 && !increase) {
      clearInterval(handle);
      toggleFontSize(selector, init, true);
    }
  }, 50);
}

toggleFontSize(document.querySelector("p"), 20);
```

```html
<p>Hello world.</p>
```

However, it might be better to just use CSS animations which is definitely smoother.

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: toggleFontSize 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes toggleFontSize {
  from {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world.</p>
```

Comment: ye. css animations are the better solution. apart from that, the scripted idea is not using requestAnimationFrame, thus could benefit from even further improvement

Comment: @GottZ Please stop changing my `init` assignment. I don't like your syntax (to each their own) and there is no benefit of using one over the other.

Comment: while i did stop adding this back in before you wrote that comment (yes, reading the edit history helps to figure out the authors intent) i'd disagree due to one fact: if you can avoid typing out variable names over and over, it usually results in less error prone code as a result. for example: if you would copy that line somewhere else to do exactly the same but with a different variable name than `init`, you might run into the typical oversight issue of changing the other two references to that variable. sorry. i'm just avoiding such possibilities in my daily programming tasks.

Comment: You don't need to apologise. If that is the way that you write code, that is fine - but I don't. My argument to *not* write it as you suggest, is because the operator `+=` assumes you are always adding to the variable and that its value will keep increasing. You have to read the whole line before you realise that it might actually decrease because depending on the condition, you'll get `init += -1`. For me, readability is important - I want to be able to just skim through quickly and get the gist. As I said, to each their own style of coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can better split the increase and decrease up in parts:

See attached JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5tzafspo/5/

```
var change = document.querySelector("p");
change.style.fontSize = "20px";
var currentSize = 20;
var minSize = 20;
var maxSize = 50;
var intervalTime = 50;

increaseSize();

function increaseSize(){

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    currentSize++;

    change.style.fontSize = currentSize+"px";

    if(currentSize === maxSize){
      clearInterval(interval);
      decreaseSize();
    }
  }, intervalTime);
}

function decreaseSize(){

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    currentSize--;

    change.style.fontSize = currentSize+"px";

    if(currentSize === minSize){
      clearInterval(interval);
      increaseSize();
    }
  }, intervalTime);
}
```